# Loop through JSON object in Twig from the database

Tags: plugin-development, templating, json

I've written a custom plugin that stores data as `JSON` in a `TEXT` column (`field_gridcontrol`) in Craft's content table that looks something like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": "35", // id is an element's id
    "classes": "item w1 h2", // classes to add to the dom element
    "x": 0 // x coordinate on where it shows up in a grid
  },
  {
    "id": "56",
    "classes": "item w2 h2",
    "x": 0.25
  },
  {
    "id": "24",
    "classes": "item w1 h1",
    "x": 0.75
  }
]
```

I can print this as a string `{{entry.fieldcontrol}}`, which is all well and good, but I'd like to be able to loop through it as an object like a traditional [element criteria model](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel):

```
<ul>
{% for block in entry.gridcontrol %}
  {% set entry = craft.entries.id(block.id) %}
  <li class="{{block.classes}}" style="left:{{block.x}}%">
    {{entry.title}}
  </li>
{% endfor %}
<ul>
```

However when I try this I don't get any errors, just an empty `ul`. I guess this is because it's not seeing gridcontrol as an object.

My question is: Did I go about structuring this the wrong way? I've seen other plugins, like [nystudio107's SEOmatic](https://github.com/nystudio107/seomatic), [that store data this way](https://cl.ly/2S2v06332k0n/Screen%20Shot%202017-01-04%20at%208.43.59%20AM.jpg). Or am I missing something super silly to get this up and running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll simply need to decode the JSON string. Unfortunately, Twig doesn't ship with a `json_decode` filter, but there's [a plugin](https://github.com/diit/Json-Decode-Twig).

Here's how you'd use it:

```
<ul>
{% for block in entry.gridcontrol|json_decode %}
  {% set entry = craft.entries.id(block.id) %}
  <li class="{{ block.classes }}" style="left:{{ block.x }}%">
    {{ entry.title }}
  </li>
{% endfor %}
<ul>
```

Comment: Perfect, this worked wonderfully. Thanks for the tip.